# How can I fix ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: react-native, npm, react-apollo

I'm trying to downgrade to an earlier package due to the metro bundler not understanding .cjs files, and me not knowing how to fix it. (I've already posted multiple questions, and everyone has told me the same thing which doesn't work.) I'm trying to install react-apollo@2.4.1 but I keep receiving this error.

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sparta-app3@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-apollo@2.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-apollo
npm ERR!   react-apollo@"2.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/frignfragr/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/frignfragr/.npm/_logs/2022-04-26T23_32_34_989Z-debug-0.log
```

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Also, what should I do if NPM is telling me I have 9 high severity vulnerabilities? I figure that's quite bad, but I'm unsure what to do and I've tried updating before but it seems to break my app because things change.

As you can tell, I am still very novice to this type of stuff.

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried using the commands suggest by the error output, i.e `--force`/`--legacy--peer-deps`? Here's an [article](https://itsmycode.com/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages/) that explains in detail.

In regards to your vulnerabilities, you can try `npm audit fix` but if updating a package breaks your code, you can either refactor your code to work with the new package api or endure the vulnerabilities warning

Comment: @HJEC I tried force and it worked for a bit until it broke. I will try legacy—peer-deps next. Thank you! And thank you for your help with the vulnerabilities as well. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the value in legacy-peer-deps to true `config set legacy-peer-deps true`
and try again with `npm install twrnc`.